# How to zoom out and animate camera when a route with poly lines is drawn on my flutter Google maps app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My flutter Google maps app draws a route between two points but often the two points dont fit on the screen, I want the user to able to see the two points, like when the user selects his location and the app draws the route from his location to his destination it should be visible and fit on the screen,hopefully with animate camera for smooth feel, any thoughts, please and thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds()` for making two points visible within the screen.

sample usage :

```
mapController.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(
          LatLngBounds(
                southwest: LatLng(
                    fromLocationLatLng.latitude <= toLocationLatLng.latitude
                        ? fromLocationLatLng.latitude
                        : toLocationLatLng.latitude,
                    fromLocationLatLng.longitude <= toLocationLatLng.longitude
                        ? fromLocationLatLng.longitude
                        : toLocationLatLng.longitude),
                northeast: LatLng(
                    fromLocationLatLng.latitude <= toLocationLatLng.latitude
                        ? toLocationLatLng.latitude
                        : fromLocationLatLng.latitude,
                    fromLocationLatLng.longitude <= toLocationLatLng.longitude
                        ? toLocationLatLng.longitude
                        : fromLocationLatLng.longitude)),100),
    );
```

you need to keep in mind following condition as used is sample above.

`'southwest.latitude <= northeast.latitude': is not true.`

Otherwise it will throw Error.

**Update :**

If you look at the [Cardinal Direction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_direction), there are specific bounds/ranges provided to each direction

```
             North (+90)
               |
(-180) West ———+——— East (+180)
               |
             South (-90)
```

For an example below 
southWest = Latlng(-7.12725588946924, 159.14) would actually be more East than  northEast = Latlng(70.0415297179124, 24.855900000000005).

And zoom will go outside the bound i.e., to the east of the given point instead southwest. You can understand more about this box  using this interative website https://boundingbox.klokantech.com/

above info after **update** is taken from https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4919

Comment: does this work so everytime the user sets two new points, it will stay centered and fit on the screen?

Comment: Yes it will make both points visible to the screen and that value of 100 is like the padding of that route to the screen. And if you want to disable user interaction of zooming of the map, so that no one can change zoom other than programmatically, you can diable it in Maps constructor.

Comment: alright thanks,i really appreciate, i understand the functionbut what about what you said about "you need to keep in mind following condition as used is sample above.

'southwest.latitude <= northeast.latitude': is not true.

Otherwise it will throw Error." what do you mean i dont understand

Comment: You don't need to worry as it is already handled in sample code above. I am updating answer do more clarification for above condition.